# Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'booking_items' I can't find this error in my database

Tags: sql

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'booking_items'

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Lassana_Flora`.`Booking_Items`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Lassana_Flora`.`Booking_Items` (
  `Booking_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Today` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Booking_Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Item_Code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Unit_Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Invoice_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Personal_Message` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Booking_Option` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Booking_ID`),
  INDEX `Customer_ID_idx` (`Customer_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Invoice_ID_idx` (`Invoice_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `Item_Code_idx` (`Item_Code` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Lassana_Flora`.`Customer_Details` (`Customer_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Invoice_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Invoice_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Lassana_Flora`.`Invoice` (`Invoice_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Item_Code`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Item_Code`)
    REFERENCES `Lassana_Flora`.`Items` (`Item_Code`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are the same column(Booking_ID) value in the data to be inserted.
It's better to write down more details. For example, sql script, db type, etc...